# creating XML files from large csv files with java and jdom

Tags: java, xml, performance, list, jdom

I have to read data from multiple csv files and convert these data to an xml file. Therefore I wrote a java program, that is reading each line, converting each line to an object and creating a list of ojects for each file.
With these lists I am then building my xml file (using jdom). Sometimes I need to search within these lists. I already implemenented binary search for this.

Unfornutately my program needs a lot of memory and is really getting slow (if the size of the csv files is larger than ~25 MB it is not possible to create the xml files).
Any ideas how to improve my performance, so that my program will also work with large csv files?

Comment: It might be because for poor implementation. Can you please share the snippet of your code so that we can help you out.

Comment: Since you have shown us no code, the only advice we can give is completely generic: use profiling to work out which part of your code is causing the trouble, then make improvements to that part of the code.

Comment: I have to admit, the cause really just was poor implementation. I found that out using JVM Monitor. So, jdom really wasn't the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I released a generic csv/ods(multiple tabs) to xml to address this kind of need in java.

You can generate lists, mappings, ..., with a template.

You can find it at https://github.com/ggsmiley/csv2xml

It is not optimized now for very large inputs (it was not the goal), but enhancements are welcome.

hope it helps